# I want to use both firebase and google map

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, gradle

Like the title I want to use both `firebase` and `google map`. 
When I try it individually, it doesn't have any errors. But If I try to use it all ERROR!! Can anyone help me fix this problem? I've tried to find some soulutions but `multidex` or making the update level same doesn't work at ALL.

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MY-APPLICATION-ID"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}





apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my gradle error.. :(

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.0.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lower the version to same as Firebase dependencies or vice versa

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
```

or

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'    
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have same version of both 
firebase and google map

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'    
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same version for Firebase as for google

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use latest versions of firebase and maps `for Example. 11.0.4`

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
```

and make sure you in project's gradle file you are using

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```